# Listener for Vaadin Timeline Chart Range selection

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-charts

i would like to display Vaadin 2 timeline charts components one below the other and both should have their own navigator and rank selector. However, both should work synchronously. As soon as I select another area on a timeline chart, I would like to get this area via listener and pass it on to the other chart. Which listener or event i need to track?
Thx for your answers